# Remove int at index in array for java powerball game

Tags: java, arrays

Almost done making Powerball game, but theres a semantic error. Trying to compare two arrays of 5 ints and return number of matches.  However if there is a duplicate number the number is matched multiple times.  I need to delete both numbers after they are matched.

I tried using arraylist as suggested on here but arraylist is "Unused import statement" and .remove is "cannot resolve method"

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if (balls[i] == yballs[j]) {
                    match++;
                    balls.remove();
                    remove(yballs, yballs[j]);
                }
            }
        }

public static int[] remove(int[] symbols, int c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
        if (symbols[i] == c) {
            int[] copy = new int[symbols.length-1];
            System.arraycopy(symbols, 0, copy, 0, i);
            System.arraycopy(symbols, i+1, copy, i, symbols.length-i-1);
            return copy;
        }
    }
    return symbols;
}
```

Comment: no any method remove in array. and you have not created any ArrayList thats why unused import. so i don't think this is the issue , your logic is missing something else

Comment: You can't remove stuff from an array. Either create a new ans smaller array or use `ArrayList`. And I mean really using it and not just importing that class.

Comment: Using `ArrayList`, you could create a new `ArrayList` to track all the duplicates you found and then call `removeAll(dupArray)` on the  Lists

Comment: or simply call `remove(value)` every time you find a match

Comment: so array list is a different thing than a array?

Comment: Absolutely. An array is a fixed length data structure while an ArrayList is an Collection of Objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution to use `ArrayList`

You could populate the 2 ArrayLists to represent the two collection of balls and the one to hold the matches:

```
List<Integer> balls = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> yballs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> matches = new ArrayList<Integer>();

balls.add(<ball number>);
...
yballs.add(<ball number>);
...
```

Then you would go through each ArrayList as:

```
for (Integer ballNumber : balls) {
    for (Integer yballNumber : yballs) {
        if (ballNumber == yballNumber) {
            matches.add(ballNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

And to remove all the duplicates from both `List`s:

```
balls.removeAll(matches);
yballs.removeAll(matches);
```

If you don't want to remove all of them and just remove one of the duplicates, you can do:

```
for (Integer match : matches) {
    balls.remove(match);
    yballs.remove(match);
}
```

Comment: When i try to do this the diamonds give error "diamond types are not supported at this language level" any idea what thats about?

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: when i put integer in there it works, i was using the latest version, i think 8

Comment: one more thing, i think this removes all the duplicates, however we  want to remove only the first pair so

Comment: 15 52 52 50 64 would become 15 52 50 64 if there was a 52 in your number

Comment: So if there is only one match, remove it. But if there is multiple of the same number in the `ArrayList`, keep one of them and remove the rest?

Comment: yeah because 50 50 50 30 30 could be numbers and then 50 50 50 30 30 could be winning match

Comment: I alse get                                                         Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
 at PowerBall_Simulator.main(PowerBall_Simulator.java:54)

Comment: Not sure how you got an Exception. I ran the above code just fine. What did you change in it?